# Duplicate entry error when inserting into table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I have a big table already in MySQL and I'm trying to create a another smaller table that consists of data from the big one. I'm using this code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS borrower (
idBorrower VARCHAR(255),
borrower_address VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY (borrower_address)
);

INSERT INTO borrower
    (idBorrower, 
    borrower_address)
SELECT idBorrower, borrower_address
FROM final_data;
```

I'm using the borrower_address as the PK because it is made up of email addresses and all of them are unique/ no duplicates. When I run the code to insert the data into the new borrower table I get the below error:

Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry 'rmeigh8g@51.la' for key 'borrower.PRIMARY'

The email address the error message is mentioning is in the first row of the big table(final_data) that I'm inserting the data from. But there is no duplicate value, it only appears once in the big table.

Any idea what might be causing the issue or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If the data does not exist in the original table, then it would appear to exist multiple times in `final_data`.  You can easily check this:

```
SELECT borrower_address, COUNT(*)
FROM final_data
GROUP BY borrower_address
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

You can fix this problem then by using `GROUP BY` or some other construct to only fetch the data once -- or use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: So something like this: INSERT INTO borrower
 (idBorrower, 
    borrower_address)
SELECT idBorrower, borrower_address
FROM final_data2
GROUP BY idBorrower, borrower_address;